# How to format date and return date in date-fns angular

Tags: angular, date-fns

We have requirement to send date of type **Date** **not of type string** without time in **yyyy-MM-dd** format. But when I tried it with **parse method** of **date-fns** then it gives error Invalid date.

My code is given below:

```
     // where given date is Thu Nov 19 2026 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale)
    console.log('date without time', parse(givenDate.toDateString(), 'yyyy-MM-dd', new Date()));
```

It gives error:

```
date without time Invalid Date
```

How can I solve it? Is it possible that we can have a date without time of **type date not string**? If someone knows then please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `parse()` method of `date-fns` requires a string as its first argument, so you can't pass a Date object directly. To convert the Date object to a string, you can use the format() method. For example:

```
import { format, parse } from 'date-fns';

const givenDate = new Date('Thu Nov 19 2026 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale)');
const dateString = format(givenDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
console.log('date without time', dateString);
```

This will output the parsed date without the time in the specified format.

Comment: It gives date without time Thu Nov 19 2026 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale). But I need date with this format yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: To format the date in the required format, you can use the format() method of date-fns. For example:

import { format } from 'date-fns';

const givenDate = new Date('Thu Nov 19 2026 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale)');
const formattedDate = format(givenDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
console.log('formatted date', formattedDate);
This will output '2026-11-19', which is the date in the required format.

Comment: format() method returns string not Date. My requirement is Date

Comment: new Date(formattedDate)

Comment: It gives Thu Nov 19 2026 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale)